# How to ignore program's output when using /usr/bin/time?

Tags: unix, shell, time, profiling, io-redirection

I want to know how long a program running, so I tried "/usr/bin/time ./program > /dev/null".
But soon I found it displays program's output to stderr. I tried "/usr/bin/time ./program > /dev/null 2>&1" then, but /usr/bin/time's output not appear.
So my question is, how to ignore program's output, and keep time's output.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `-o` flag to send the output from time to something else then `stderr`. For example, if you still want it on screen:

```
/usr/bin/time -o /dev/tty ./program >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Or, if you want output on `stdout` very badly:

```
/usr/bin/time sh -c './program >/dev/null 2>&1'
```

or similar. However, now you're also measuring the shell's time to start the process, which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using another python script to read the output to know how long it takes. Can I use this command?

Comment: You could redirect the output to a pipe and have your other program read from that.  Or can your other script simply start a timer, exec the program, then read the timer when the program completes?

Answer (score 1):

(Unable to comment)

It might be nicer to use a subshell:

```
/usr/bin/time ( ./program > /dev/null 2>&1 ) 2>&1
```

Or better yet a compound construct:

```
/usr/bin/time { ./program > /dev/null 2>&1; } 2>&1
```